# Disable Laravel Emails - BeautyMail

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm looking for a way to disable sending of ALL emails from within Laravel. I'm working with a local deveopment copy of a website, and it's been sending off emails to actual users which is the last thing I want during testing.

What I've done:

I went into config/mail.php and added the following line:

```
    'pretend' => true,
```

Additionally, there was some configuration in the .env file related to Mailgun (a domain and secret) which I've removed, so that there should be no possibility of connecting to Mailgun.

After this, the system continues to send out emails during testing. My understanding was that setting 'pretend' to true should be enough to route all email sending to the log file.

It's worth noting that the system is using BeautyMail, which to my understanding is just an email templating system. It does, however, look like the email that keeps going out is sent using the BeautyMail send() function:

```
$beautymail = app()->make(\Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class);
    $beautymail->send('emails.templates.testemail', compact('url'), function ($message) use ($email) {
        $message->from(Mailer::$sender)->to($email)->subject('Test email');
    });
```

How can I disable this, and be sure that the system will not continue to fire off emails to actual users from my development environment?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

did you try to set
`'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'log'),`
in your config/mail.php or 
`MAIL_DRIVER = log`
in .env

Comment: you saved me from a lot of pain :)

Comment: I suggest verify if is running a test, to avoid modify the default, like this
'driver' => env('APP_ENV') == 'testing' ? 'log' : env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

Comment: now it's `MAIL_MAILER=log`

Answer (score 1):

### Official documentation for Laravel 6.x

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#mail-and-local-development

> Instead of sending your emails, the log mail driver will write all
>   email messages to your `log` files for inspection. For more information
>   on configuring your application per environment, check out the
>   [configuration documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration#environment-configuration).

It also shows you how to use Mailtrap for free, which is great.

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of Laravel (I use 8.x)

Change `.env` file

```
MAIL_MAILER=log
```

to send it to logs

OR

```
MAIL_MAILER=array
```

to ignore it completely

Answer (score 0):

you can use mailer local server like

[MailDev is a simple way to test your project's generated emails during development with an easy to use web interface that runs on your machine built on top of Node.js.](https://github.com/maildev/maildev)

in env

MAIL_MAILER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=localhost

MAIL_PORT=1025